# how to add an attachment image to view in requisition and po approval notification in line level?

Tags: oracle

how do I add an attachment image to view in requisition and po approval notification in line level? not the view detail page, it should  be the main notification page. there is   a table in requisition notification for the line detail but i can't see any attachment image in the personlize create item button ,

and for po notification, the table for line looks like a html like table, I wonder if it  can be personlzied to add a column for attachment image, anyone can share the technique for doing this? thanks

Comment: In the pr approval notification I have added  attachment image in the table with view instance  :ReqLinesNotificationsVO

entity mapping entity:REQ_LINES

primary key :RequisitionLineId

but it is still not working

Comment: What platform are you working on?

Comment: You're not being specific enough about your development environment. It may be clear for you, but anyone reading your description might as well guess what you're dealing with.